# React renders full component instead of what changed when using wrapper function

Tags: reactjs, components, render, reactive, rerender

I observed below when rendering a list component. The list component is taking a search prop and filtering before rendering.

```
 <UserList pattern={search}/>
```

when using above statement directly inside parent component, it renders only what changed based on search prop (list remains and only unmatched items got removed)

But when I wrap the UserList in another function like below:

```
const Users = ()=>  <UserList pattern={search}/>;
```

and use `<Users/>` in parent component, I see that whole list component re-renders when search prop changes. search field is a local state (useState['']).

so, the parent component looks like this now :

```
const App = () => {
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

const Users = ()=>  <UserList pattern={search}/>;

return (
    <div id="app" className="home-page">
      <Header />
      <WelcomeSlogan/>
      <Users/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So we know that react re renders full child component(s) if parent component changed, but in this case how the parent (`<Users>`) is changing exactly? Can someone explain to help me understand better? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you defining the `Users` component? Could you provide the code so that we can reproduce the behaviour you are experiencing?

Comment: In same file. It's just one line component.